# Http-server running in background with nohup doesn't remain live

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, httpserver

I have an ubuntu server. On which I have transferred some files which have some js and html code.

I used http-server from node.js to start a web server so that I can display the html page on the server.

I used nohup so that it can remain running even if I disconnect or close my system.

Here is the command I used:

```
nohup http-server -p 8000 -a 10.4.145.182 &
```

Now this helps me visualize the files on `10.4.145.182:8000` but I am noticing after sometime the server goes down and one can't access the html page on that ip in their browser.

I thought nohup helps run things in background even if one closes their system or logs out of server.

How do I make this web server running always then and accessible to url to everyone

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As per the suggestion below of using pm2, I installed latest version of node and then started service with pm2.

It says service started for http-server but when I go the to ip with port 8000 on browser it doesn't open up.

Here is the command I ran in my directory which has the html and d3 files.

```
$ pm2 start $(which http-server) -p 8000
```

And here is the output in shell of the pm2

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
http-server & exit
```

You can also specify a port number:

```
http-server -p 8082 & exit
```

Reference [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/106910)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use pm2 . Long story short , check the official link https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

Steps :
Install :

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

Run your app :

```
pm2 start app.js
```

In your case use :

```
pm2 start /usr/local/bin/http-server --  -p 8080
```

for reboot to work run :

```
pm2 startup systemd
```

take the last line , change the user and home path and run the modified line as SUDO !!! you need sudo access for this !!!

Comment: I don't have any js script as such. I just start a web server using http-server and then I have html, d3 files in the directory which I can visualize on the ip url. How do I get a web server started without this js script

Comment: check the post please

Comment: I did this in the dir where my files are there. Nothing happened. I don't see the files rendered on that ip path and port. I got the pm2 intalled. And now after running below I do 

pm2 list- shows nothing 


pm2 start /usr/local/bin/http-server --  -p 8080 -a 10.4.145.182

Comment: Added Edit. Pm2 works but ip doesn't open up in browser

Comment: Sorry :) I used 8080 and you expect 8000 , change the port to 8000 :)

Comment: ah I changed that in my code. didn't use urs. Still same issue

Comment: restart without -a option  and run >>> curl localhost:8000 <<< on the same server , is this working ?

Comment: not using -a option anymore My host is the ip address of the ubuntu server. Does localhost work there?

Comment: btw i am anyway not using -a option in pm2

Comment: Could u help me figure this out? as shown in screenshot, it does say its running but I can't seem to connect it via the browser. The ip doesn't open on browser

Comment: restart without -a option and run >>> curl localhost:8000 <<< on the same server , is this working ?

Comment: ran pm2 start $(which http-server) -p 8000. Then ran curl localhost:8000. Curl printed the whole html file in console. But when I go to browser with the IP and port, same issue. Doesn't open anything.

Comment: Btw I tried another setup with nginx. Console works fine but still no connection to browser. See the ques I put here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54893111/running-a-web-server-using-node-js-pm2-and-nginx

Comment: run the curl from another computer, 90% you will get nothing. In this case check the network configuration, firewall . Try again with the old command , use another port, check if with this one is working.

Comment: I figured this one out. Its because nginx is using 8080 as default and hence the port to be specified in url should be 8080 and not 8000. 8000 is pm2 http-server running. It goes via nginx which has 8080 as default. So for user it shud be 8080

Comment: I think the http-server is started to 2 times if you find it on 2 ports. Try a restart and check the results after restart