# Running a web server using node.js (pm2) and nginx

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I have different projects some using flask code and some plain html/d3 files. I want to viz them on the web for any user to access the insights.

I came across this process of using pm2 and nginx as a good way to keep the server running forever and also have the ability to run multiple apps on the same ubuntu host ip.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-18-04

I did everything as mentioned in the tutorial and while running pm2 to start a web server using http-server I see the following.

```
$ pm2 start $(which http-server) -p 8000
```

[image]

For nginx I did the following after installing nginx on ubuntu

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Then I entered the following config in nginx/sites-enabled/default file

```
server {

     location /sunburst {
        root /home/web_apps/;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

I want to run this app on 8000. I also read I can add another location block with another port and app name for another app to run on same host ip.

After doing all this, I restart nginx

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

It says restarted nginx in console and pm2 screenshot is shown as above.

But when I go to the host ip in browser and type:

```
10.4.145.182:8000
```

It doesn't show anything and says can't connect. When I just enter 10.4.154.184 I get default nginx message.

I am not sure where I am going wrong and how to get that running on browser. I am stuck in this for days and any help would be advisable.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `10.3.153.192/sunburst`? Nginx runs on port 80 per default and you set the `/sunburst` location for your application.

Comment: When I do IP:8080/sunburst it runs but not just with <iP>/sunburst. btw the ip is changed as above

Comment: Where do you want your application to be running?

Comment: 10.4.154.184. Currently it is running but I need to put the path as 10.4.154.184:8080/sunburst. If 8080 is default nginx then shudlnt it take 10.4.154.184/sunburst? It doesn't for me

Comment: have you tried `... location /sunburst/ {...` as per this [question]?(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-run-multiple-node-application-with-nginx-same-droplet-same-domain)